# PrimeNG cascading dropdowns: initialize child dropdown

Tags: dropdown, primeng

How do I initialize the child dropdown based on the value of the parent dropdown?

**app.component.html**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="states" [(ngModel)]="selectedState" (onChange)="getCities($event.value)"></p-dropdown>
<p-dropdown [options]="cities"></p-dropdown>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  cities: SelectItem[];
  selectedState: string;

  stateNames = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'California'];
  states = this.stateNames.map((val, i, stateNames) => {
      return { label: val, value: val }
  });  
  cityNames = [
    {state: 'Alabama', city: 'Birmingham'}, 
    {state: 'Alabama', city: 'Huntsville'}, 
    {state: 'Alabama', city: 'Montgomery'},
    {state: 'Alaska', city: 'Anchorage'}, 
    {state: 'Alaska', city: 'Juneau'},
    {state: 'California', city: 'Fresno'},
    {state: 'California', city: 'Perris'}
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCities(this.selectedState);
  }

  getCities(state):any[] {
    this.cities = this.cityNames
                      .filter((el) => { return el.state === state })
                      .map((el) => { return { label: el.city, value: el.city } });
  }  
}
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/robUcF?p=preview)

Comment: What is not working in your Plunker ? Everything seems to be ok...

Comment: On initial loading, the parent dropdown is populated, but the child dropdown is empty. Ideally, the child dropdown should also be populated. Of course, the child options should match its parent. Only after the parent dropdown is changed is the child dropdown populated. How do I populate the child dropdown on the initial loading?

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize `selectedState` with the first country from `stateNames` in `ngOnInit` :

```
this.selectedState = this.stateNames[0];
```

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N9jclkn9jhVK1fYdbY84?p=preview)

Comment: That fixes it. Thank you. I still don't understand why the ngModel binding is not working in this instance.  I was assuming that `selectedState` would have been populated in `ngOnInit`. I guess that has to be a question under a new topic.

Comment: I guess it can be unwanted to assign it in some cases so it should be to the developer to do it informed.